# use table's timestamp column(without timezone) as EST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, psql

I have a `table 'A'` in db which have a `column 'x'` of `type 'timestamp without timezone'` and in rails project I have set timezone to 'EST'. Everything works fine when I create/update record from my project.

The problem is that I imported data from another DB using PSQL. 'x' column have the same time as in old DB but when I use `'ActiveRecord'` query, I get '+05:00' offset. I am confused how to tell `'ActiveRecord'` that that time is already in 'EST'?

here is a solution by me.

```
=> A.first.x.to_s(:db)
# "1900-01-01 21:47:00"

=> A.first.x
#Mon, 01 Jan 1900 16:47:00 EST -05:00
```

but is there any other better option ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding following to application.rb must work

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

or Every zone you wish

Comment: I have tried that already, if I use this setting then it return `nil` instead of time

Comment: Have you tried it to get that time on rails console? and object is date and time ? Please add your result for that column here

Comment: added, I am trying this through console

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your time in 'EST' time zone **in your query**.

You can find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652623/how-to-convert-time-to-date-in-the-local-timezone-during-query)